jQuery in display function of a Python notebook
Is there a way to run jQuery in a display function called in a Python notebook ?
I am looking to be able to organize (sort) some div produced and displayed in a notebook.
The static js+html version works. Not from a notebook.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import HTML, display

width = 300
height = 200
dpi = 100


# Create images
for i in range(5):
    filePNG = 'image_%02d.png' %(i+1)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(width/dpi, height/dpi), dpi=dpi)
    plt.plot(np.random.rand(10))
    plt.ylabel('some numbers')
    plt.savefig(filePNG)
    plt.close(fig)

# Display
html_code = ''
for i in range(5):
    filePNG = 'image_%02d.png' %(i+1)
    html_code += '''
                    <div style='float: left; border: 1px solid lightgray;'>
                            <img style='width: 100%%;' src='%s' />
                    </div>
                 ''' % (filePNG)
js_code = '''
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.14.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( function() {
            $("#sortable").sortable();
        });
    </script>
            '''

display(HTML(js_code + '<div id="sortable">' + html_code + '</div>'))


As written the same code works from an html page.
For info: https://jqueryui.com/sortable/
Is it feasible with a ipywidget output ?

I have also tried with some pure javascript. Without success...
const plots = document.querySelector('#sortable').querySelectorAll('.plot');
plots.forEach(plot => {
  console.log('plot');
  plot.addEventListener('dblclick', function handleClick(event) {
    plot.remove();
  });
});
</script>```

Double click should remove a plot div.

The issue is that you're using the wrong jQuery version. You need to use the same jQuery that the notebook is using (currently 3.5.1) otherwise you are going to end up with two conflicting versions.
You can check the jQuery version in the Jupyter notebook with:
display(Javascript('alert($().jquery)'))

Here's your working code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import HTML, Javascript, display
import base64

width = 300
height = 200
dpi = 100


# Create images
for i in range(5):
    filePNG = 'image_%02d.png' %(i+1)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(width/dpi, height/dpi), dpi=dpi)
    plt.plot(np.random.rand(10))
    plt.ylabel('some numbers')
    plt.savefig(filePNG)
    plt.close(fig)

# Display
html_code = ''
for i in range(5):
    filePNG = 'image_%02d.png' %(i+1)
    html_code += '''
                    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.14.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
                    <div style='float: left; border: 1px solid lightgray;'>
                            <img style='width: 100%%;' src='%s' />
                    </div>
                 ''' % (filePNG)

js_code = '''
        $( function() {
            $("#sortable").sortable();
        });
'''
display(HTML('<div id="sortable">' + html_code + '</div>'))
display(Javascript(js_code))

Actually, you don't need to upload any of the jQuery or jQuery-UI libraries since they are already available in the notebook. You can see this with
display(Javascript('alert("jQuery: "+$().jquery + ", jQuery-UI: " + $.ui.version)'))

(I get JQuery: 3.5.1, JQuery-UI: 1.12.1)
So the code will work also if you remove the lines
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.14.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>


Thanks for having tested this.
So nice that jQuery already embeded.
I haven't been able to sort. What is wrong ?

@PBrockmann One reason could be that you are using the id="sortable" in some other cell. Try to change the id name

No. Not working. I get from a empty notebook with just your code (without lines to load jquey and jquery-ui the error: Javascript Error: $.uniqueSort is not a function.
What am I missing ? jupyterlab updated to  4.2.5

I still don’t get it. Even with a pure JS.
Try:
https://thredds-su.ipsl.fr/thredds/fileServer/ipsl_thredds/brocksce/tmp/display_js_01.ipynb
→ plot should be sortable
https://thredds-su.ipsl.fr/thredds/fileServer/ipsl_thredds/brocksce/tmp/display_js_02.ipynb
→ a double click should remove the div

Any news ? Has someone tested ?
